# New Django project admin urls are somehow being overridden by prior project Django-Allauth settings

Tags: django, django-admin, django-urls, django-allauth, django-cache

I have a new project, using DRF, and when trying to login to admin panel I get an error stating that the page not exist. The problem is that the url being generated when entering the current url is the same url that I used in my prior project using Django-Allauth. I have checked the current project for any traces of Django-Allauth and there are none. I checked the DB to make sure it was empty upon initiation of the project, and it was. What could be the problem here?

`current url.py`

```
    urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        ...,
    ]
```

`prior urls.py`

```
    path("accounts/", include('allauth.urls')),
```

When I try to login to admin on localhost:
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/` it redirects to old project's path of: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/?next=/admin/login/%3Fnext%3D/admin/` resulting in an error stating `page not found`. I cleared cache by restarting project with Pycharm's `Invalidate Cache/Restart` but that did not resolve the issue. Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Have you set `LOGIN_URL` in your settings?

Comment: Yes. I hard coded it just now to `'http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/'` to see if that would fix it. But now the error message is `127.0.0.1 redirected you too many times`